# Accessing site running inside the Guest VM (Ubuntu LAMP) webserver running over Max

Tags: macos, ubuntu, apache-http-server, nat, vmware-fusion

I'm running Vmware Fusion on a Mac (host) inside which I am running VM  (Ubuntu + LAMP) hosting sites like say example.com (and few other sites).

When I try to access example.com from inside the Guest it works fine and I get the proper webpage .
My example.com.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

VM is setup with default Network Adapter configuration (using NAT).

I am able to get to WebServer properly from host (mac) for example 
172.X.X.X/ takes me to "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" OR 
172.X.X.X/phpmyadmin/index.php will allow me to log into php admin account.

but when I try 172.X.X.X/example.com/. I get

```
Not Found
The requested URL /example.com was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 172.X.X.X Port 80
```

I want to use NAT as long as it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question after looking at apache logs and help from others

First thing I changed my website's apache conf file to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerName <ServerIpAddress>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html**/>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I made changes to /etc/hosts file to include include the site as

```
<localhostIp>       localhost
<localhostIp>       ubuntu
<ServerIpAddress>   example.com example.com
```

After I made the changes, I can access site from outside the server